# For what kind of sets, the distance function is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

If $\Omega$ is closed subset $\mathbb{R}$, then the distance function 
$$f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \,\,\,\, x\mapsto d(\Omega,x),$$
is certainly a continuous function. An interesting property of this function is that, the points where $f$ vanishes is precisely the closed set $\Omega$.
However, this function is not necessarily differentiable: when $I=\{0\}$, then $f(x)=|x|$, which is not differentiable at $0$.

My question is, can we find other non-closed nice sets (like open sets, or some others) $\Omega$, for which $f$ above will become differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$? Can we characterize such sets?

(The obvious examples would be dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, for which $f$ will be constant function $0$.)

Comment: It seems that $f$ is not differentiable at the "boundary" of $\Omega$.

Comment: you may be correct; for specific types of sets $\Omega$ it is true

Comment: If $\Omega$ is not closed then $d(x,\Omega)$ is the same as $d(x,\overline{\Omega})$ so asking about non closed sets reduces immediately to the closed case.  If $\Omega$ is closed and not all of $R$ then in any component interval of $R\setminus \Omega$ it is abundantly clear what the function $d(x,\Omega)$ looks like and exactly where the corners are.  So I think the problem is a dead end.

Comment: Related to: [Is the distance function differentiable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836179/is-the-distance-function-differentiable). For later readers who may be interested, this question is currently an active research area for infinite dimensional normed spaces. See Jon D. Vanderwerff's comments [here](http://faculty.lasierra.edu/~jvanderw/ConvexFunctions/Notes/distancefun.pdf), and more generally, see the google search ["closed set" + differentiable + distance](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22closed+set%22+differentiable+distance).

Comment: The "distance to a closed set" function is Lipschitz continuous (with Lipschitz constant $1),$ so the topic falls within the more general study of the differentiability properties of Lipschitz functions. However, I believe the special case of "distance to a closed set" includes many of the important results and counterexamples of the general theory, so the study of the differentiability properties of the distance to a closed set function is an important special case in the general theory of the differentiability properties of Lipschitz functions defined on normed spaces.

Answer (score 5):

I try an answer.

Suppose that $f(x)=d(x,\Omega)$ is differentiable, and $\overline{\Omega}$ is not equal to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $U=\mathbb{R}-\overline{\Omega}$, and $]u,v[$ a connected component of $U$; we have $u,v\in \overline{\Omega}$.

Then for $x\in ]\frac{u+v}{2},v]$, we have $f(x)=v-x$, hence $f^{\prime}(x)=-1$. In particular, we have $f^{\prime}(v)=-1$. Then for $|x-v|$ small, $x\not =v$, we have $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)-f(v)}{x-v}\leq -\frac{1}{2}$. Hence as $f(v)=0$,  for $x>v$, $x-v$ small, we get $f(x)<0$, a contradiction. The case of $]-\infty,v[$ and $]u,+\infty[$ can be shown to lead to a contradiction on the same way. So $\overline{\Omega}$ must be equal to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Nice answer. I was not expecting myself that only dense sets would give differentiable functions. But, good to see this surprise.

Comment: You could simplify the last part of the argument by noting that $f$ has a global minimum in $v$ (in fact, in each point of $\overline{\Omega}$), so that $f'(v) = 0$.

Comment: @phoemueX. Yes, you are true, thank you

Comment: Seems rather simpler to say that if $\Omega$ is a nonempty closed set that is not all of $R$ then there is a point that is isolated on at least one side.  At that point $d(x,\Omega)$ cannot possibly be differentiable.  (Closed or not is irrelevant since $d(x,\Omega)=d(x,\overline{\Omega})$ for any set.)