Derivative of (squared) distance function
Consider some closed and convex set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^m$, where $m\in\mathbb{N}$. I am looking for a reference (in form of a paper or a book) concerning the differentiability of the distance function
$$x\mapsto \text{dist}(x,A) = \inf\limits_{y\in A}\|x-y\|_2$$
for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^m \setminus A$. Also any differentiability results concerning the square distance function $x\mapsto \text{dist}^2(x,A)$ are very welcome. Unfortunately my knowledge about this topic is very limited, hence I was only able to find respective results in some forums online, but I would like to cite a paper or a book if possible. Thanks in advance!

Why there are parentheses in the exponent $2$? Does your notation $x^{(2)}$ means something different from $x^2$?

With this notation I only wanted to highlight that I am very glad about any reference that either concerns differentiability of the distance function $\text{dist}(x,A)$ itself, but also any differentiability results for the squared distance function $\text{dist}^2(x,A)$ (which probably may exist more likely) are welcome.

Well, that notation is not standard at all, so you should explain that in the question. Or better state that your interested in both $\text{dist}(x,A)$ and $\text{dist}^{2}(x,A)$, because may be the case that one is differentiable while the other don't.

If you consider strictly convex distance functions, then Solution is unique. You can discard inf. The rest is straightforward

Take a look at these questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836179/is-the-distance-function-differentiable ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502775/is-a-distance-function-differentiable-on-bbb-rn ;

Yeah its the standard Euclidean norm, I edited the post. Thanks all! @Yves Daoust: That's absolutely fine - now you know!

It is true that if $|.|$ means the euclidian norm then $A$ convex and closed entails $d(.,A)^2$ differentiable (and even $C^1$. The converse is also true. There are some Have a look there :https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247694/differentiability-of-distance-to-a-closed-convex-set and also there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645580/how-to-prove-squared-distance-is-differentiable

This question is similar to: How to prove squared distance is differentiable? + Winther's two linked posts. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. + Better ask a single question in a post, not two like here.
